# Event.add for keypress does not work?

Tags: tinymce, keypress

We are trying to use tinyMCE for one of our applications. We would like to attach some event handling to particular elements within tinyMCE. We've tried doing it using

```
Event.add(element, 'keypress', getTag);
```

Where *element* is the HTML element we are trying to attach the event to and *getTag* is the function we'd like called when the keypress event is fired. The particular element we are trying to attach to is a span element with some text in it. We'd like to capture when particular key combinations are entered(like ctrl - F10) between the span tags and popup a menu with options.

The options in the menu will vary depending on the particular span elements the combination is entered in. That's why we want to attach to particular elements instead of globally attaching to all span elements in the document(within tinyMCE). i.e The getTag function will behave differently, using closures, depending on where the combinations are entered.

The problem is when we attach to the particular elements and test them nothing happens for any 'keypress' events. If we try to attach to the span elements using a 'click' event everything works as expected. Once we revert back to using 'keypress' nothing happens again.

Using the debugging tools I've verified a couple of things. The event listeners are attached to the elements. It seems tinyMCE creates a toplevel keypress and click(along with others) to the document within tinyMCE. I'm guessing this is how Editor.onKeyPress().add() like functions work. When I debug the working scenorio using click I can see where the event is fired for both the document and span elements. While debugging the keypress event I only see the event fired for the document element, not the span element. I'm thinking that tinyMCE is suppressing the event, but I can't figure out how, and what needs to be done to stop it.

Comment: so basically , you want to enter F10 and if the caret is inside a span element in the editor a speciall function should be executed?

Comment: yes, that's basically what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this handler eigther in one of you own plugins or using the tinymce config param [setup](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup)

```
ed.onKeyDown.add(function onkeydown(ed, evt) {

   var is_in_span = ed.selection.getNode().nodeName == 'SPAN';   


   // check for caret in SPAN and F10-Key
   if (is_in_span && evt.keyCode == '121'){ // you may add other keyCodes here
      // do whatever you like here
      ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Thariama. I should have been a bit more clear in my response comment above. This doesn't quite answer my problem, but does give me an idea to an alternative solution. Not only do I need a popup when F10 is pressed within a SPAN element. I need the popup to have different options based on the particular SPAN element F10 is pressed within. The particular options depend on the parent elements of the SPAN element. I'm now thinking I'll just add some attributes to the element to detect the difference when the document is created and then incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: sounds like you will just have to look for attributes of ed.selection.getNode().parentNode in case the former node is a SPAN